# Ho to remove duplicate items in csv file in Jmeter

Tags: csv, jenkins, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have a Jmeter script that saves the output to a CSV file. In the output (CSV) file, I want to remove the duplicate items in the URL list(3rd column). How can I do this?

The sample line in csv file are the following:

```
responsecode, responsemessage,url 
404,Not Found,http://test1 
404,NotFound,http://test1 
404,Not Found,http://test2 
404,NotFound,http://test3 
404,Not Found,http://test2
```

Expected:

```
responsecode, responsemessage,url 
404,Not Found,http://test1 
404 Not Found,http://test2 
404,Not Found,http://test3
```

Anyone can help how to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a CSV file which looks like:

```
200,OK,http://example.com
404,Not Found,http://example.com/foo
200,OK,http://example.com
404,Not Found,http://example.com/bar
```

and want to transform it into the following one:

```
200,OK,http://example.com
404,Not Found,http://example.com/foo
404,Not Found,http://example.com/bar
```

1. Add [tearDown Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#tearDown_Thread_Group) to your Test Plan
2. Add [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) to the tearDown Thread Group
3. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
    def dedup = new File('original.csv').readLines().collectEntries { [it.split(',')[2], it] }

    dedup.entrySet().each { entry ->
        new File('without-duplicates.csv') << entry.getValue() << System.getProperty('line.separator')
    }
   ```
4. Replace `original.csv` with the relative or full path to your CSV file and `without-duplicates.csv` with the desired name/location of the file without duplicates

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: I tried the code but it did not create the file without duplicate. Also, CSV has field name on the first row. using the provided script seemed to not be working

Comment: Your CSV file contains spaces, if it is expected you will need to change `it.split(',')[2]` to `it.split(',')[2].trim()` in the above example code snippet. I would like to remind you that this is not a code writing service and I'm not your personal telepathic JMeter troubleshooting assistant. [Groovy syntax](https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html) is not a big secret, neither is [The Groovy Templates Cheat Sheet for JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-groovy-templates-cheat-sheet-for-jmeter)